# Access to my ranking to make an average for my user

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to make a average of the ranking by user.
I actually have a model review which is belongs_to post/push/user models. 
Whose action is to use two variables in the ranking table which are: user_id: & :rating.
Currently, I have no errors in my pages, but the average is still at zero whereas normally he have associed rating.

My code

Profiles_controller/ action show:

```
def show
    if @user.cooker?
     @pushs = Push.where(taked_by: @user.id).reverse
     @reviews = Review.where(user_id: @user.id)
       if @user.reviews.blank?
        @average_review = 0
      else 
        @average_review = @user.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
      end 
    else 
      @pushs = @user.pushs.reverse
    end
  end
```

Profiles show view :

```
    <h2> Avis moyen :</h2>
 <div class="average-review-rating" data-score= "<%= @average_review %>">

      <script>
    $('.average-review-rating').raty({
      readOnly: true,
      path: '/assets/',
      score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score')
      }
      });
    </script>
```

routes :

```
resources :posts do 
    resources :pushs do 
      resources :reviews
    end 
  end
```

If you have any ideas of why there is no average in my profile view, You will be my man !!

Comment: Does `@user.cooker?` return `true`, and does `@user.reviews.blank?` return `false`? (What flow path is your code following?)

Comment: Yep they return what you said. What do you mean by flow path ? I include my routes if this can help to understand better

Comment: I'm guessing something is up with the association between `User` and `Review`.  If you open your rails console, what is returned when you call `.reviews` for that particular user?

Comment: @tagCincy It return all the review created by the particulat user, so no notes for the User Profile (which is represented by the variable user_id into the Review model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to skip the second condition, this code should work well without it:

```
if @user.cooker?
  @pushs = Push.where(taked_by: @user.id).reverse
  @reviews = Review.where(user_id: @user.id)
  @average_review = @user.reviews.average(:rating).try(:round, 2)
else 
  @pushs = @user.pushs.reverse
end
```

Comment: It return me the error : "undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass", and when I errase this part of the function, there is no average un the profile page

Comment: @jeanZaniloi I edited my answer to fix it. Do you have `User has_many :reviews` association in your `User` class ?

Comment: Thanks man I have no error for run, but I still don't have any average. Yep, normaly, i maked all the association. But I must have made a mistake somewhere. The strange think is that when I try to apply that in my show/push, this action is perfectly working ! It annoys me

Comment: @jeanZaniloi try execute this code in your `rails console` does it return average rating correctly ?

Comment: I don't realy know how to use the console, how can I call that action ?

Comment: @jeanZaniloi it's described there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console

Comment: Thanks I look at this now, I know that I have to learn the console to test the app runing quickly